# pyspark column transformation

Tags: list, pyspark

I have two predefined lists as below.

```
East = ["Bengal", "Bihar", "Assam"]
West = ["Bombay", "Gujarat", "Goa"]
```

I have a pyspark dataframe as below. I need to add a third column (State) in the dataframe depending upon the name in the second column after searching in the lists(City).

df:

```
Num    City     
1      Bengal   
2      Goa      
3      Bombay   
4      Bihar
```

Expected output:

```
Num    City     State
1      Bengal   East
2      Goa      West
3      Bombay   West
4      Bihar    East
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try anything? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Show your work on solving this problem and let us know where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isin` function.

```
East = ["Bengal", "Bihar", "Assam"]
West = ["Bombay", "Gujarat", "Goa"]

from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df.withColumn("state", when(col("City").isin(East), "East")\
    .when(col("City").isin(West), "West").otherwise(None)).show()

+---+------+-----+
|Num|  City|state|
+---+------+-----+
|  1|Bengal| East|
|  2|   Goa| West|
|  3|Bombay| West|
|  4| Bihar| East|
+---+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I could do only in pandas as below. Since the dataset is huge, I am trying do convert this into pyspark. Thanks.

Pandas code as below

```
def map_state(name):
    #print(name)
    East = ["Bengal", "Bihar", "Assam"]
    West = ["Bombay", "Gujarat", "Goa"]
    if name in East:
        return 'East'
    if name in West:
        return 'West'   
    else:
        return name

df['State'] = df['City'].apply(map_state)
```